# Passing location in subarray as string

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

I have a function that searches a multidimensional array for a key, and returns the path 
inside the array to my desired key as a string.

Is there any way I can use this string in php to reach this place in my original array, not to get to the value but to make changes to this specific bracnch of the array?

An example:

```
$array = array('first_level'=>array(
                   'second_level'=>array(
                          'desired_key'=>'value')));
```

in this example the function will return the string:

> 'first_level=>second_level=>desired_key'

Is there a way to use this output, or format it differently in order to use it in the following or a similar way?

```
$res = find_deep_key($array,'needle');
$array[$res]['newkey'] = 'injected value';
```

Thanks

Comment: I've read this twice but no success to understand your problem.

Comment: So you want to search that example array for `"desired_key"` and get back, `first_level => second_level => desired_key` ? And you then want another function to use that string version to get the value of that key? Why do two processes when the first function can just return the value straight away?

Comment: What is the point of all of this actually ?

Comment: Thanks smokey and Brewal, I edited the last line of my question. I am not after the value inside, I am trying to alter the array in a specific place.

Comment: And what's the expected output of your code?

Comment: @Jack, I am, passing this array to another function that needs the injected value to work. Ultimately this code will create a logging system. This part is for the many javascripts to handle a new item in their json. 
All the $array[$res] paths are hard coded in the javascript, and they process values only beneath this level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys path is safe (e.g. not given by the user), you can use `eval` and do something like:

```
$k = 'first_level=>second_level=>desired_key';
$k = explode('=>', $k);
$keys = '[\'' . implode('\'][\'', $k) . '\']';

eval('$key = &$array' . $keys . ';');

var_dump($key);
```

Comment: pNre, thanks for going through my difficult phrasing and understanding what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a recursive search in the array for your key? Correct me if i am wrong.

Try this

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
   foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
      $current_key=$key;
      if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
        return $current_key;
      }
   }
return false;
}
```

Taken from here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#91365

Comment: Once I get this key, how can I access the subarray in order to make changes? This is assuming the desired key is deeper then one level.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
find_key_in_array($key, $array, function($foundValue){

  // do stuff here with found value, e.g.
  return $foundValue * 2;

});
```

and the implementation would be something like:

```
function find_key_in_array($key, $array, $callback){

  // iterate over array fields recursively till you find desired field, then:
  ...
  $array[$key] = $callback($array[$key]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to append some new sub-array into multidimensional complex array and you know where exactly it should be appended (you have path as a string), this might work (another approach without `eval()`):

```
function append_to_subarray_by_path($newkey, $newvalue, $path, $pathDelimiter, &$array) {
    $destinationArray = &$array;
    foreach (explode($pathDelimiter, $path) as $key) {
        if (isset($destinationArray[$key])) {
            $destinationArray = &$destinationArray[$key];
        } else {
            $destinationArray[$newkey] = $newvalue;
        }
    }
}   

$res = find_deep_key($array,'needle');
append_to_subarray_by_path('newkey', 'injected value', $res, '=>', $array);
```

Of course, it will work only if all keys in path already exist. Otherwise it will append new sub-array into wrong place.

Answer (score -1):

just write a function that takes the string and the array. The function will take the key for each array level and then returns the found object.

such as:

```
void object FindArray(Array[] array,String key)
{
if(key.Length == 0) return array;

var currentKey = key.Split('=>')[0];
return FindArray(array[currentKey], key.Remove(currentKey));
}
```

Comment: Where did you see java in the question ?